# Change device on google find my device?

Tags: lost-phone

I just had one of my android phones stolen, thankfully it was just a backup burner phone, but I still used my google account on it. I though I should be able to either find or wipe it from google's "Find My device" android.com/find , however it does not let me change the device like I can if I'm on the web google play store. It only shows my main device. Is there any way to get this to switch to my other device?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't show up on the app, it's probably because the person who stole it has done a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset). If that is the case it will not show up on the web version too

I just checked using the app and devices associated with my account show up when if they are switched off

Comment: None of my other devices show on the site I mentioned. If you are talking about something other than android.com/find please specify.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood. I thought you were referring to this [Find my device](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.adm) app by Google. If you can't see it in the web version, factory reset is the most likely cause

Comment: Another possibility is that devices (other than the one stolen) were not used for a long time and hence don't show up. Log in those devices and they should show up